# Getting file modification time in POSIX shell

Tags: shell, files, date, posix

Is it possible to get file modification time from shell using only POSIX features? Ideally in unix timestamp (seconds).

Everything I was able to find was using `stat(1)` but that does not seem to be defined in POSIX. Is it possible?

Comment: Similar: [Full file date (without GNU utilities)](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/255524)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only POSIX CLI (shell and utilities) interface to the `lstat()` and `stat()` system calls is `ls` I'm afraid and its output is not post-processable reliably.

A trick could be to use `pax -x ustar` (both the `pax` command and its `ustar` format are specified) to generate a `tar` file with the file in it and extract the timestamp from the file.

```
echo "$((0$(pax -x ustar -wd -- "$file" |
    dd 2> /dev/null bs=4 skip=34 count=3 | tr -d '\0')))"
```

The `mtime` being stored at offset 136 as an octal number.

It's encumbered by all the limitations of US-tar format though.

Your best bet portably would be to use `perl` or `python`:

```
perl -MPOSIX -le '
  for (@ARGV) {
    if (@s = lstat$_) {print $s[9]} else {warn "$_: $!\n"}
  }' -- "$file"
```

(note that it doesn't include the nanosecond as available on many modern systems. You may be able to get it via the `Time::HiRes` module for instance, but that assumes it's installed and it's from a recent version).

Comment: That's amazing!

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a POSIX compliant OS (which seems to be assumed from your question), there is a nice way to do this using `pax` that allows to even get fractions of a second.

Call:

```
pax -xpax -wd -- "$file" | dd 2> /dev/null skip=1 count=1 |
    grep ' mtime=' | sed 's/.*mtime=//'
```

If I call:

```
pax -xpax -wd -- /etc/passwd | dd 2> /dev/null skip=1 count=1 |
    grep ' mtime=' | sed 's/.*mtime=//'
```

I get:

```
1572569707.797017689
```

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't reliably use `dd` on a pipe unless you use `bs=1` or GNU specific options like `iflag=fullblock` as `dd` could do short reads. You can't use `grep`/`sed` POSIXly on binary input either, so you'd need to strip the NUL bytes. `dd 2> /dev/null bs=1 skip=512 count=512 | tr -d '\0' | sed -n 's/.*mtime=//p'` would be more portable.

Comment: This does not seem to be correct. The definition of a pipe is that the read size depends on the write size and `PIPE_BUF` (the maximum that is granted to be written atomically). Since `pax` uses a write size of 10kB and `PIPE_BUF` is 5kB (on older UNIX variants 4 kB), there is no problem to read the first two `512` byte units from the pipe, the way I propose. Given that the potential null bytes in the `grep` input are **after** the matching part (in contrast to what you proposed before) there is no problem with `grep` and `sed` does not see null bytes.

Comment: The behaviour of `grep` and `sed` is unspecified on non-text input. See how GNU `grep` for instance reports a `Binary file (standard input) matches` if it detects its input is non-text, even under `$POSIXLY_CORRECT` as that's allowed by POSIX.

Comment: AFAICT, there's nothing in the `pax` specification that mandates it to do I/O in writes of multiples of 512 bytes (though in practice it's very likely to be the case). The minimum value of PIPE_BUF guaranteed by POSIX is 512. You seem to be confusing UNIX (a trademark claimed by a variety of different operating systems) with Solaris or a family of SysV-derived OS-es.

Comment: Of course, the POSIX standard mandates that `pax` writes blocked data and that the blocking factor depends on the achive format. For `tar` and `pax` the standard blocking factor is 10 kB. Given that you admit that POSIX grants a minimum value of 512 for `PIPE_BUF`, there is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's rather simple to work out, but here's a variation employing python.

```
#-- cross-platform workaround, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/561927/3097
alias stat_mtime='python -c "print(__import__(\"os\").stat(__import__(\"sys\").argv[1]).st_mtime)"'

$ stat_mtime /dev/null
1624731195.3483574
```